# Angular storing server data in a global service. How do I ensure it is there

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a globalDataService in my app that reads a couple of entities from the server.

I only want to read the data once, and then serve it up via a method on the service. Here's a simplified version

```
angular.module("myApp").factory("globalData", ["siteResource", globalData]);

function globalData( siteResource) {
    var sites = [];
    siteResource.query().$promise.then(function(data){
          sites = data;
    },
    function(response) {
        //handle bad stuff
    });

    var getSites = function () { return sites; }

    return { getSites: getSites };
 }
```

and in my controller I just want to be able to do this

```
this.sites = globalData.getSites();
```

and know that the data is there, and if it isn't then something is wrong. What do I need to do in my service to make this happen, I've just wasted 2 hours trying to do something with $q but with no joy.

It's pot luck whether the globalData service has loaded the data or not when I need it, particularly when the app first loads....

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/chrisronline/angular-promise-cache. You want to return ```promise``` from your factory which resolves to cached result and fetches it if does not exist. You can resolve ```promise``` by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the promise and **return** the promise. Create the promise **once** and reuse it.

```
angular.module("myApp").factory("globalData", ["siteResource", globalData]);

function globalData(siteResource) {
    var promise;

    function getSitesPromise () {
        if (!promise) {
             promise = siteResource.query().$promise;
             promise = promise.catch( function (error) {
                  //handle bad stuff
             });
        };
        return promise;
    };

    return { getSitesPromise: getSitesPromise };
}
```

Comment: perfect, thank you, the missing link for me was making the service return a promise...

Answer (score 0):

What your are doing is pretty simple.
Prob making $http requests to your server to get data. But you don't want to make them every time just on init.

you can use $q like this ...

```
  var promise1 = $http.get('/mypath1');
  var promise2 = $http.get('/mypath2');
  var promises = $q.all([promise1, promise2]); // resolves when all promises are resolved OR will reject when ONE promise rejects
  promises.then(function(arrayContainingAllServerResponses) {
      // do something
  }).catch(function(error) {
      // oops one of the requests failed
  })
```

sorry but i dont have time for more detail - this might get you on the right track - cheers

this works because $http returns a promise :)

Remember if your have a promise then you can call THEN on it - the THEN code will be executed when the promise is resolved (not immediately). You can even chain THENs by returning a promise from a THEN. Hope this all helps.

If a method returns a promise then you can call THEN on its return value. REMEMBER $http returns a promise which is resolved or rejected when your server responds or the request times out!